# Trouble styling data for viewing in open layers using XML

Tags: xml, postgresql, postgis, geoserver

I have uploaded data for postGIS, now I want to style the data in geoserver. I This is done in XML. After adjusting the code, I am getting an error message that says:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
  The requested Style can not be used with this layer.  The style specifies an attribute of PolygonAcres and the layer is: lab4:wa_publiclandsinventory_2014_publicinfo
```

Here is my XML code that has been altered to display two groups of data large parks and small parks in WA state from a statewide data set downloaded from the WA GIS database found [here](http://www.rco.wa.gov/data/index.shtml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
<sld:NamedLayer>
<sld:Name>public_land_classificiation</sld:Name>
<sld:UserStyle>
<sld:Name>public_land_classification</sld:Name>
<sld:Title>Public Land classification</sld:Title>
<sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
<sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
<sld:Rule>
<sld:Title>Large Parks</sld:Title>
<ogc:Filter>
<ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
<ogc:PropertyName>PolygonAcres
</ogc:PropertyName>
<ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
<sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
<sld:Fill>
<sld:CssParameter
name="fill">#FF0000</sld:CssParameter>
</sld:Fill>
<sld:Stroke/>
</sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
</sld:Rule>
<sld:Rule>
<sld:Title>Small Parks</sld:Title>
<ogc:Filter>
<ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
<ogc:PropertyName>PolygonAcres
</ogc:PropertyName>
<ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
</ogc:Filter>
<sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
<sld:Fill>
<sld:CssParameter
name="fill">#0000FF</sld:CssParameter>
</sld:Fill>
<sld:Stroke/>
</sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
  </sld:Rule>  
</sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
</sld:UserStyle>
</sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

PolygonAcres is an attribute with numerical values from 0-70000 acres or so. I have tried working with other attributes but get basically the same error using the property is equal to state, federal, and local governments using three "rules" to style by different color. Let me know if you need more information..

Comment: Maybe the column name in Postgis is lowercase? `polygonacres`. Add to the question the exact table definition as you see it in psql.  PS:which geoserver version are you using?

Comment: PolygonAcres is typed exactly as it is represented in the excel spreadsheet...2.7 snapshot?

Comment: Check what the field name is in your layer.  I've had sources that I've imported where the casing wasn't what I expected.  As Tommaso is suggesting, what matters to Geoserver is what is listed in the Feature Type Details.  These are located on the bottom of the page of the Edit Layer screen.

Comment: ok able to view it now! Got to go to work...I'll check back in afterwards

Comment: Tommaso and Jason you are right, polygonacres was not capitalized...thanks a bunch for showing me the obvious problem that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a return at the end of your propertyName so change

```
<ogc:PropertyName>PolygonAcres
</ogc:PropertyName>
```

to

```
<ogc:PropertyName>PolygonAcres</ogc:PropertyName>
```

Comment: No, this is not the issue. Geoserver recognizes the fields in both cases

Comment: I even styled the same layer/data but in a different workspace through explorer to what I would like and it still gives me the same error...I even get the same error basically when using a completely different set of data. I'm not sure what is going on here..